# What Disney kit has part number 35347 with vines sticker on it?

Tags: set-identification

What Disney kit has part LEGO Cylinder 3 x 6 x 6 Half with Tower with vines Sticker (35347) on it? Have all the set in pieces but the manual has been lost so do not know which manual to look for.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description and the element number, the only set I found matching this description is [41154: Cinderella's Dream Castle](https://brickset.com/sets/41154-1/Cinderella-s-Dream-Castle)

[image]